# I want a failover for my Uipath Orchestrator without using HAA. I want my Standard orchestrator to switch to Basic Orchestrator is that possible?

Tags: uipath, orchestration, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I have a standard orchestrator but if it goes down as a failover, I want my basic orchestrator to take its place so there would be no difference felt by the end-user. I want that without using HAA provided by UiPath.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Redis instead but it is an unsupported method.